# Cannot run docker:dind as docker:docker

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

I cannot run docker:dind as docker:docker even I intuitively should:

```
[sad@localhost ~]$ docker pull docker
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/docker
540db60ca938: Already exists 
5a38b3726f4b: Already exists 
e5fa5deb3340: Already exists 
2b7e0e3b7545: Already exists 
493333e9491f: Already exists 
28d445cfca76: Already exists 
32eb6dfb9227: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:ad50b8d78b41dc52f42ab123ce0e3f48c54437ed70ecc2a44c99e889924c8e56
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker:latest
docker.io/library/docker:latest
[sad@localhost ~]$ docker run --privileged -d docker:docker
Unable to find image 'docker:docker' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for docker:docker not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.
See 'docker run --help'.
[sad@localhost ~]$
```

Is this by design, that I should reference the docker:docker image as docker:dind?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change

```
docker run --privileged -d docker:docker
```

into

```
docker run --privileged -d docker:latest
```